# C# how to deserialize XML string which has nested same node

Tags: c#, xml, xml-serialization, xml-deserialization

```
<n-hierarchy>
    <n name="ABC" n_id="971" />
    <n name="XYZ" n_id="972">
        <n name="jkl" n_id="973">
            <n name="wer" n_id="974"/>
            <n name="cvb" n_id="975"/>
        </n>
    </n>
</n-hierarchy>
```

above is the sample XML string which I receive from an API and I want to deserialize into a C# object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try following :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;


namespace ConsoleApp10
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);
            XElement hier = doc.Descendants("n-hierarchy").FirstOrDefault();

            Node root = new Node();
            root.name = "root";
            root.parse(hier);
        }
    }
    public class Node
    {
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string id { get; set; }
        public List<Node> children { get;set;}
        
        public void parse(XElement element)
        {
            foreach (XElement childElement in element.Elements("n"))
            {
                if (children == null) children = new List<Node>();
                Node child = new Node();
                children.Add(child);
                child.name = (string)childElement.Attribute("name");
                child.id = (string)childElement.Attribute("n_id");
                child.parse(childElement);

            }


        }
    }

}
```